# Защита от CSRF - токены. Если пользователь откроет вторую страницу - то старая будет неактуальна

Tags: csrf

Сделал у себя так, что при каждом обновлении страницы - генерируется в сессию новый csrf токен. Но вот что заметил, если пользователь сидит на одной странице - к примеру редактирования своих данных, и открывает другую вкладку с сайтом - то ему дается новый токен, то есть на старой странице - он больше запросы слать не сможет, так как токен уже будет другой.

Как это решается? Или я неправильно реализовал систему проверки токена?

Answer (score 1):

Мои варианты:

1. Храните в сессии не один токен, а массив. С адресами страниц (для http и https токены должны быть разные) на которых каждый токен используется и метками времени. Токены из массива удаляйте по мере их использования или истечения времени жизни.
2. Храните в сессии ключ. Для каждой страницы генерируйте токен на основании этого ключа, адреса страницы и ip-адреса пользователя. Можно дополнительно использовать метку времени для определения времени жизни токена (при длинной сессии). Тогда итоговый токен будет состоять из хэша и метки времени.